# How to transform XML as a string w/o using files in .NET?

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

Let's say I have two strings:

- one is XML data
- and the other is XSL data.

The xml and xsl data are stored in database columns, if you must know.

How can I transform the XML in C# w/o saving the xml and xsl as files first?  I would like the output to be a string, too (HTML from the transformation).

It seems C# prefers to transform via files.  I couldn't find a string-input overload for Load() in XslCompiledTransform.  So, that's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Here's what I went with.  It's a combination of your answers. I voted up the answers that inspired this:

```
string output = String.Empty;
using (StringReader srt = new StringReader(xslInput)) // xslInput is a string that contains xsl
using (StringReader sri = new StringReader(xmlInput)) // xmlInput is a string that contains xml
{
    using (XmlReader xrt = XmlReader.Create(srt))
    using (XmlReader xri = XmlReader.Create(sri))
    {
        XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
        xslt.Load(xrt);
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        using (XmlWriter xwo = XmlWriter.Create(sw, xslt.OutputSettings)) // use OutputSettings of xsl, so it can be output as HTML
        {
            xslt.Transform(xri, xwo);
            output = sw.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Note: this statement is required in the xsl, in order to output as HTML:

```
<xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
```

Comment: can someone show me a small sample of strings of both xml and xsl? or point me to a resource that shows all of this. I'm having trouble forming the strings because of double quotes around the attribute values.

Comment: @Rod: Use @ and then double the double quotes:

 `myString = @"<root xmlns=""http:foo.namespace"" />`

Comment: StringReader is in System.IO

Answer (score 6):

You can [XmlReader.Create() from a StringReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z042k543.aspx) or a [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/756wd7zs.aspx) . XslCompileTransfrom can [Load() from an XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163424.aspx).

Comment: I'd use a StringReader to pass to the XmlReader.Create, actually.

Answer (score 6):

It took me a long time (literally years) to work out how concise code using `Stream` and/or `TextWriter` can be if you use the proper idioms.

Assuming `transform` and `input` are strings:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
using (XmlReader xrt = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(transform))
using (XmlReader xri = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(input))
using (XmlWriter xwo = XmlWriter.Create(sw))
{
   XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
   xslt.Load(xrt);
   xslt.Transform(xri, xwo);
}
string output = sw.ToString();
```

Comment: -1: Robert, why isn't `sw` in a using block? In fact, both of the `StringReader` instances should be as well. They won't be automatically disposed when the `XmlReader` instances are.

Comment: Aactually the `using` blocks for the `XmlReaders` are unnecessary.  The only object that it's really essential to `Close` in this scenario is the `XmlWriter`, so that any pending writes to the `StringWriter` get flushed before you get the results.  Putting the `StringWriter` *inside* the `using` block would make it possible that the `XmlWriter` wouldn't be flushed and closed before you got the string's value.

Answer (score 1):

I send the xml content and then load the XSLT document, apply the transformation and then return the new xml.

```
public static string Transform(string xmlString)
{
    string output = String.Empty;
    try
    {
        // Load an XML string into the XPathDocument.
        StringReader rdr = new StringReader(xmlString);
        XPathDocument myXPathDoc = new XPathDocument(rdr);

        var myXslTrans = new XslTransform();
        //load the Xsl 
        myXslTrans.Load("XSLTFile.xslt");
        //create the output stream
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        XmlWriter xwo = XmlWriter.Create(sw);
        //do the actual transform of Xml
        myXslTrans.Transform(myXPathDoc, null, xwo);
        output = sw.ToString();
        xwo.Close();
        return output;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", e.ToString());
        throw;
    }
}
```

NOTE: "XSLTFile.xslt" It is added to the solution and set the property "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy always".

Answer (score 0):

edit: using-blocks added

```
// input-xml
string xmlinput = String.Empty;
// xslt
string xsltinput = String.Empty;
// output-xml
string xmloutput = String.Empty;

// Prepare input-xml
XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(new StringReader(xmlinput));

// Prepare XSLT
XslTransform xslt = new XslTransform();
// Creates a XmlReader from your xsl string
using (XmlReader xmlreader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xsltinput)))
{
    //Load the stylesheet.
    xslt.Load(xmlreader);

    // transform
    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        xslt.Transform(doc, null, sw);

        // save to string
        xmloutput = sw.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just using'ified. Now using blocks. Okay like that? Thanks for feedback.

Answer (score 0):

A VB.Net version inspired by Robert Rossney's answer:

```
Private Function TransformXML(XMLPath As String, XSLPath As String) As String
    Dim XSLT As XslCompiledTransform = New XslCompiledTransform()
    Dim sWriter As StringWriter = New StringWriter
    Dim xReader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(XMLPath)

    Using xWriter As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(sWriter)
        XSLT.Load(XSLPath)
        XSLT.Transform(xReader, xWriter)
    End Using
    Return sWriter.ToString
End Function
```

Answer (score -2):

I would use the `XmlReader.Create(DatabaseBlobStream)` and `XmlWriter.Create(StringBuilder)` overloads.  Using the following DatabaseBlobStream object

### DatabaseBlobStream.cs

```
internal class DatabaseBlobStream : Stream
{
    private readonly IDataReader reader;
    private readonly int columnIndex;
    private long streamPosition;

    internal DatabaseBlobStream(IDataReader reader, int columnIndex)
    {
        this.reader = reader;
        this.columnIndex = columnIndex;
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get
        {
            return reader.GetFieldType(columnIndex) == typeof (byte[])
                   && !reader.IsDBNull(columnIndex);
        }
    }

    public override bool CanSeek
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        throw new Exception("This stream does not support writing.");
    }

    public override long Length
    {
        get { throw new Exception("This stream does not support the Length property."); }
    }

    public override long Position
    {
        get
        {
            return streamPosition;
        }
        set
        {
            streamPosition = value;
        }
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        if (reader.IsDBNull(columnIndex))
            return 0;

        int bytesRead = (int)reader.GetBytes(columnIndex, streamPosition + offset, buffer, 0, count);
        streamPosition += bytesRead;
        return bytesRead;
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        throw new Exception("This stream does not support seeking.");
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {
        throw new Exception("This stream does not support setting the Length.");
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        throw new Exception("This stream does not support writing.");
    }

    public override void Close()
    {
        try
        {
            reader.Close();
        }
        finally
        {
            base.Close();
        }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        try
        {
            reader.Dispose();
        }
        finally
        {
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ben, what is the advantage of this approach over Henchman's or Moog's?

Comment: How would you use that DatabaseBlobStream class to transform a XML string?