# How to transform an xml structure generated from a request to a web services

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, transform, streamwriter

I have a string var that store an xml from a request to a RESTful service.

I have a problem transforming this with an xslt file on a fly without saving it.

I am getting this error

`System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The Uri scheme is too long.` On this line

```
xslt.Transform(xmldoc, null, writer);
```

---

```
string xmldoc = xReq("http://restful.com/RestAPI");

XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();

xslt.Load(@"C:\Users\XSeXml\xRes.xslt");

string htmlOutput;

StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

xslt.Transform(xmldoc, null, writer);

htmlOutput = writer.ToString();

Literal1.Text = htmlOutput;

writer.Close();
```

Comment: is your scheme too long? If you tried to save writer at disk does it works? If you don't tried yet, test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to transform XML as a string w/o using files in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384306/how-to-transform-xml-as-a-string-w-o-using-files-in-net)

Ideas from the link above helps to overcome the problem by passing the string to the XmlReader before transforming it.